# Homomorphic image of ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

I read Craig Huneke's paper "Hyman Bass and Ubiquity: Gorenstein Rings", in which he gave a definition.

"Let $S$ be a polynomial ring and $R$ be a homomorphic image of $S$ of dimension
$d$."

Then does he mean that $R$ is just a subring of $S$. I believe there must be some ring $A$ and $R=im(A\to S)$, which means $R$ is not just a subring of $S$, but also isomorphic with $R/Ker(A\to S)$. The problem is I do not know $A$?

Was I wrong? Can you give me the true explanation?

Comment: It certainly sounds like to me that  $R = S / I$, for $I$ some ideal of $S$.

Comment: No, it is the image of a homomorphism$S\to A$ on the contrary, i.e. it's isomorphic to a quotient of $S$.

Comment: @Bernard - our comments crossed. To be clear to the OP (given that your post starts with "no"), I believe we are agreeing - but I haven't read the (famous) paper: you used $A$ in your comment. Is there some $A$ in the paper, with $R \subset A$?

Comment: Tks. Sorry for this basic question

Comment: @peterag: the `No` was referring to the question of the O.P. (‘I believe…’). I didn't read the paper either, by my $A$  refers to the formulation and notation in the question.

Comment: Actually, I got confused about the 'famous' paper - I was thinking of Bass's famous paper, which I have not read - either! Oh, for shame. Nor have I read <fill in the blank>...